# Need help understanding C struct

Tags: c

I am a newbie who has started programming embeded systems and I am working with someone else's code. However, there is a struct definition that I do not help to understand.

```
struct PACKED {
        uint8_t cmd;
        uint8_t int_status;
        uint8_t v[14];
    } rx, tx = { cmd : REG_ADDRES | 0x80, };
```

I would appreciate any help to understand the `cmd : REG_ADDRES | 0x80,` line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C way to declare `struct` object and initialize it. IMHO should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand the way that it initializes it.

Comment: In C++ (and in C too) using that syntax is a compiler *extension*, it's not the standard way of memberwise initialization. C++ doesn't even have memberwise initialization. Also note that only the `tx` variable is initialized, not the `rx` variable

Comment: A good example of BAD PRACTICE

Comment: @juanchopanza how do know it is C not C++? can explain? how do you find the difference?

Comment: @lakesh Maybe it isn't C either. The initialization syntax is not standard C++.

Comment: Can someone explain what exactly is doing the initizalization with the `:` and the `|`?

Comment: | stands for bitwise-OR, and : stands for value you are specifying for the lhs that appears left hand side of :

Comment: @Eneko The `|` is the normal bitwise or operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is combined struct type definition, and definition of two variables of that type. So it is same as code below, except code below is fixed to use the C designated initializer syntax:

```
struct PACKED {
        uint8_t cmd;
        uint8_t int_status;
        uint8_t v[14];
};

struct PACKED rx; // uninitialized, do not use until initialized elsewhere
struct PACKED tx = { .cmd = REG_ADDRES | 0x80 }; // cmd field initialized with value
```

Note that entire `tx` is initialized above, the fields that are not given explicit value are initialized to 0.

And if you wonder what `REG_ADDRES | 0x80` means, it is simple integer expression, a calculation using *bitwise OR*, so it sets bit number 7 as one, and takes other bits 0..6 from `REG_ADDRES` as they are there.

Comment: I think `PACKED` is here a macro to make the struct packed, not its name

Comment: On a side note, "fields that are not given explicit value are initialized to 0" might depend on the compiler and optimization option. Good answer though :)

Comment: @glglgl Hmm, that is quite possible. It would certainly make sense.

Comment: @giant_teapot While I can't dig out the relevant standard snippet, I'm fairly sure that for both arrays and structs, if you initialize one item, entire thing will be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

What the line `tx = { cmd : REG_ADDRES | 0x80, };` is doing is that it is initializing an object named `tx` of type `PACKED` whose first variable (i.e. `uint8_t cmd`) is getting initialized with the value `REG_ADDRES | 0x80` (which is the bitwise OR of `REG_ADDRES` and `0x80`).

In code, it is the same as:

```
struct PACKED
{
    uint8_t cmd;
    uint8_t int_status;
    uint8_t v[14];
};

main()
{
    struct PACKED tx;
    tx.cmd = REG_ADDRES | 0x80;
}
```

Comment: I think `PACKED` is here a macro to make the struct packed, not its name.

Comment: @glglgl In that case, there must be a definition of the macro PACKED. Moreover, it has to be used in a different manner as well!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, this part defines the contents of this variable.

It is an extension of the compiler you use; C99 defines it in a slightly different way. There you would write

```
struct PACKED {
    uint8_t cmd;
    uint8_t int_status;
    uint8_t v[14];
} rx, tx = { .cmd = REG_ADDRES | 0x80 };
```

This way of declaring things is quite dangerous, though, as it is wasy to skip that indeed only `tx` is init'ed.

A better way would be

```
// first declare the struct as a type
struct PACKED uart {
    uint8_t cmd;
    uint8_t int_status;
    uint8_t v[14];
};
struct PACKED uart rx;
struct PACKED uart tx = { .cmd = REG_ADDRES | 0x80 };
```